# How to get dependency list in gradle

Tags: groovy, gradle

I'm developing a plugin for gradle, that will check license types for dependencies. I didn't find anything in plugin API how to get dependency list for the project and then retrieve it's metadata (like license type).

Is it possible in gradle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For analyzing dependencies in general, check out `Configuration` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html), in particular `Configuration.resolvedConfiguration` and `Configuration.incoming`.

That said, Gradle's dependency model doesn't capture licenses. Unless you have some external service that you can query for this information, the other option is to parse Maven/Ivy module descriptors.

Gradle doesn't currently give direct access to Maven/Ivy module descriptors. Instead you'll have create a detached configuration, populate it dynamically with dependencies pointing to the descriptors, resolve the configuration, and parse the descriptors yourself (e.g. with Groovy's excellent `XmlSlurper`). It's not trivial, but doable.

Another approach is to use the license reporting capabilities of repository managers such as [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/home/v_artifactory_opensource_overview) combined with [Black Duck](http://www.blackducksoftware.com/products/black-duck-suite).

Comment: What do you mean under detached configuration? Should we create new one and add to the configuration container?

Comment: As I understand, we already have some configurations like 'compile', 'testCompile' etc. As I found, we can get the list of jar files for each configuration.

Comment: Probably it should be enough to get the pom file, or did I miss something?

Comment: A detached configuration is a standalone configuration that's not attached to the configuration container. It's created with `ConfigurationContainer.detachedConfiguration(...)`. Getting POMs directly from configurations such as `compile` will only work for archives that contain their POM. Often this isn't the case.

Comment: Why just resolving each configuration (compile, testCompile etc.) isn't an option? As I understand we will get the same list of jar files, won't we? What the purpose for creating detached configuration?

Comment: Can it help us to get pom folder (from caches)?

Comment: A detached configuration is simply a configuration that's not added to the `configurations` container. If you resolve the configurations as-is, you'll only get the main artifacts (e.g. Jars), but not the POMs. The cache layout is an implementation detail and often changes between Gradle versions, so it isn't safe to make assumptions about it.